# Альтернативный способ узнать температуру hdd в linux

Tags: linux, hdd

Есть ли альтернативный способ узнать температуру hdd без использования утилит вроде `hddtemp`? Скажем, чтобы узнать загрузку CPU, можно вызвать `top`, а можно прочитать файл `/proc/cpuinfo`. По аналогии хочу откуда-нибудь "прочитать" температуру hdd, если это возможно.

Comment: Megacli64 -PDList -aAll / grep Temp - покажет температуру всех дисков

Comment: @ДмитрийПеров в вопросе: «без использования утилит вроде hddtemp». а вы приводите даже и не утилиту, а вообще какую-то левую поделку. это не ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Эмм, напрямую просить у S.M.A.R.T диска?

```
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   124   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       38
```

При помощи, smartctl, например `smartctl -a /dev/sda` ...

Answer (score 1):

Используйте lm_sensor Там можно и утилиты вызывать и библиотекой пользоваться в своих программах.

Comment: @Sergry не подскажите, как библиотека называется? Что-то не могу найти.

Comment: **не подскажите, как библиотека называется?** В дистрибутиве Ubuntu пакет называется: "lm-sensors" is a hardware health monitoring package for Linux. It allows you to access information from temperature, voltage, and fan speed sensors. It works with most newer systems.

This package contains programs to help you set up and read data from
lm-sensors.

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя. Для чтения S.M.A.R.T. диска потребуется одна из дополнительных утилит (`smartctl` или `hddtemp`). Ядро S.M.A.R.T. не читает.